# CM 10.1.3 randomly freezes, and stock ROM phone does the same

Tags: system-freeze

Using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (P3110) on CM 10.1.3 RC3, and a Sony Xperia E (C1505). My tablet randomly freezes with no reason. Sometimes it's 9 or 10 hours after it's last turned-on, sometimes it's 10 minutes. I would just put it as "normal side effects" if it weren't for that fact that my phone freezes at the same time.

They freeze within 3 seconds of each other, until reboot (remove and reinsert battery on phone, hold power for 10 seconds on tablet) and this seems to always happen on the same WiFi. However, this sometimes happens when "separated" (not linked via WiFi or Bluetooth), though a lot rarer.

Please help, I don't understand what is going on, or why.

Comment: As a side question, suggestions for tags? I can't really think of enough.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to when the devices freeze? Do they freeze at the same time, and for how long? Do they eventually become operational again or do they both require resets? Also, are the devices connected somehow? (same Wifi network, bluetooth, etc.) having them both freeze at the same time consistently means something is going on - but we need more detais.

Comment: @ZeroPaladn I'll add this to the question. They freeze until reboot (remove and reinsert battery on phone, hold power for 10 seconds on tablet)  and this seems to always happen on the same WiFi. However, this sometimes happens when "separated" (not linked via WiFi or Bluetooth), though a lot rarer.